# irregular time series data interpolation

Tags: matlab, time, interpolation

i'm a newbie in Matlab. after using a specific application, i get a file which contains a data acceleration recorded every 160ms.

```
16  25  50  32  234 199 6

16  25  50  192 240 196 3

16  25  50  352 236 199 8

16  25  50  512 238 198 7

16  25  50  671 242 195 11

16  25  50  832 237 198 9
```

as we saw here that the interval value vary between +/- 160ms, its not fixed .
the 4 first column designed a 'data time series' and the rest designed a data acceleration.

here sample rate is not constant. so my goal is how can i get a data acceleration every 160ms.
i was thinking to resample data acceleration by interpolation.
first, i convert my data to seconds

```
s=data(:,3)+data(:,4)/1000; % convert to seconds+fractions
dt=diff(datenum(2013,1,1,data(:,1),data(:,2),s))*86400;
```

> t= cumsum(diff(datenum(2014,06,09,data(:,1),data(:,2),s))*86400);

```
sample = interp1(t,data(:,5:end),[0:160:t(end)]);
```

is that correct?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're doing already with all that `diff`/`cumsum` stuff by I would think make `t` start at 0:

```
t = datenum(2013,1,1,data(:,1),data(:,2),s)*(24*60*60);
t = t-t(1);
sample = interp1(t,data(:,5:end), 0:0.16:t(end));
```

The idea here is that we know we want to sample every 0.16 seconds but only relative to the starting time. So if we reset the starting time to be 0, then we can just use 0:0.16:(end time - start time) as our sampling vector. The easiest way to make the start time 0 is to simply subtract the start time from the whole time vector, hence `t = t - t(1)`. This also has the bonus effect of make `t(end)` equal the end time minus the start time.

Comment: So you're saying my first method works by my second doesn't? What doesn't work about it?

Comment: thanks for your answer. but the code is below doesn't work. we should do a time difference between readings . you're right that t should start from 0.                                                           t=[0; cumsum(diff(datenum(2014,06,09,data(:,1),data(:,2),s))*86400); My code gives me a result but the problem how can i calculate now a sample rate? it is 1/160? i was trying the twice but it gived me an error message

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are saying. However, I've spotted the error in my code, it should be going in steps of 0.16 since `t` is measured in seconds and not milliseconds. I don't agree with you about taking the differences, you don't need to do it. I'm pretty sure my second piece of code now does what you want.

Comment: i appreciate your help. thanks a lot. i wille explain exactly for what i search. as we know that normally the rate sampling(frequency sample) should be a constant value but as we saw here its vary(when you see the value between interval is varied between 159,160,161- colum 4 th). .so my challenge is to let the value of this rate constant, for this reason, i was think for interpolate function in other hand , your code works well  but when i see the result,        0
0,16
0,31999
0,48
0,63899
0,8
0,95899
1,119
1,28
1,44
1,6
1,76
1,92
2,08
2,24
2,399
2,559
2,719
2,879
3,04
3,199

Comment: i still see the difference between interval varies betwenn 159,160,161  . it's not possible to fixed the interval  to 160ms(0.16 s).

Comment: No `t` is not the results timesteps, it is the input. `0:0.16:t(end)` is the resulting timesteps and they will be spaced exactly 160 ms apart.

Comment: as i understand that now the interval between is fixed to 160 ms? by the way,  i saw the data acceleration which is modified. i like to apply a filter method, should i use a modified data? 
234 199 6
240 196 3,0001
236 199 8
238 198 7
241,97 195,02 10,987
237 198 9
239,99 198 10,006
239 198 11
239 198 11
242 195 8
241 196 8
242 195 8
241 196 8,9999 . please an you explain me mor why the data modified. i think that i don't understand what did exactly interp1 . thanks in advance

Comment: Of course it's modified, that was the whole point. You wanted to change you sampling so now you're looking at different points on your signal. Since it's not flat, they have different values. Regarding the filtering I think rather just ask it as a new question.

Comment: thanks a lot. i have writtem a code about the filter which i will use. just i'm stuck in the value of sampling rate . sampling rate is define as  the number of samples obtained in one second (samples per second), thus fs = 1/T. can i consider that the value of T= 160ms. it's correct? (T here is the interval between sending data. thanks in advance.

Comment: please i have an error message when i like to plot for example data(:,2) vs Time(t), the code is: plot(t,x); it showed me this error:Vectors must be the same lengths. it appears normal that gives me an error as we added a row to t (we added 0). have you any idea how to slove it. thaks in advance

Comment: @user3602893 This is a new question, create a completely new question please.

Comment: the problem is the first column (0), is necessary to set 0 in beginng of t

Comment: @ Dan: please can you explain me why did you do by this line : t = t-t(1);

Comment: @user3602893 Added an explanation to the question